# how to show an only specific html element in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron

I want to the show just specific form field on Electron window as will in following example. How can I do this in Electron ?

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<div id="body">
    <div class="content">

        <!-- FROM HERE-->
        <form class="form_class" method="POST" action="/">
            <input type="text" class="login_input" name="login_input" placeholder="username">
            <input type="submit" class="login" name="submit" value="Continue">
        </form>
        <!-- TO HERE -->

        <div class="conte">
            <img src="image.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a HTML/CSS/JS question, not Electorn-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window && window.process && window.process.type` like this:

```
if (window && window.process && window.process.type) {
    // Code to show form field.
}
```

[How to detect if running in electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2288)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already installed [node.js package manager](https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.9.1/node-v8.9.1-x64.msi) Now you need to go to this link [electron Quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) 
now do as instructed in the **how to use** section:

```
# Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
# Go into the repository
cd electron-quick-start
# Install dependencies
npm install
# Run the app
npm start
```

this will run your electron app. Now all you need to do is change the **index.html** file with the desired view you want.